# How to create a new action in a folder in document library in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have to create new action in folder inside document library.I have been trying to add an action but its not working out. I wan the action to available in this menu:

[image]

Need some help in the implementation. When I go into Alfresco Share interface, I see the concept of sites. I decided to create a site for our application. Then inside the site, I am able to create folders underneath the site, I also see a document library location, inside which as well I can create folders

I am having a hard time choosing or deciding on an approach. Tried implementing the concepts on repo but not sure how to reflect the changes in UI using share.

Comment: Alfresco provide [a tutorial on adding custom doclib actions](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-action-doclib.html) - did you try it? If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: +1 for Gaggravarr. You can also follow this tutorial : http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Only the default actions are visible,no change is seen

Comment: I can certify you that the links we gave you work. If you didn't succeded, you need to show us what you have done so far (with you code), so we can understand what's missing.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.